# WPF: how create this background colors

Tags: wpf

[image]

Please ignore the `Title bar` and all `Tabs`.
Just the main grid.

This is what i have try:

```
<Grid>
                                <Grid.Background>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.504,1.5" StartPoint="0.504,0.03">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#282828" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0.567"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Grid.Background>
                            </Grid>

RESULT
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,1" EndPoint="1,0" >
            <GradientStop Color="#310D42" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#673F52" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I am not near my computer now so I will take a look once I get back home, any chance to add Screnshot meanwhile?

Comment: Yes that great, any chance to add this style also to the upper title bar? (You can remove it and use border instead)

Comment: This is much harder due to the fact that Windows controls that area. It can be done, but it's difficult if you want full functionality (drag etc) so probably best left for a separate question.